# Transistor amplifier keeps flickering between working and off

Tags: transistors, audio, sound

So long story short, i got some speakers from an old music player and they are huge (around 2.5 inches diameter and 1.5 inches high), i gave them new wires to use with a breadboard so i used a headphone jack to connect it to my computer. But it was too quiet, even with both youtube and my computer at max volume, so i made a simple transistor amplifier, but for some reason the outputed audio is flickering, i can tell that the audio data from the jack is getting through correctly because you can still sortof hear the melody of the test music, 3.3v is going through the transistor to the speaker, with the flow controlled by the current coming from the jack. I have also noticed that the speaker clicks more frequently with chiptune (or similar).[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transistor is used as an emitter-follower (look it up) that has a voltage gain of only 1. So the output volume will be low level like for headphones.
The transistor is not biased so it behaves as a rectifier producing severe distortion (flickering?).
Your very simple circuit feeds DC through the speaker that a real amplifier never does.

Answer (score 0):

consider something like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcFarT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>